# My laptop wont boot from ubuntu installation disc

Tags: 12.10, cd

I just burned Ubuntu 12.10 x64 to a DVD (cd is too small) and put it in my laptop. When I rebooted, there was a violet screen and that keyboard logo. And then a black screen with _ in top left corner. It won't let me write anything in it. I have HP pavilion G7 1303em.

I ALREADY HAVE WINDOWS 7 x64 ON MY LAPTOP AND I WANT TO INSTALL UBUNTU ALONGSIDE WINDOWS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following tricks:

1. When that violet screen and the logo appeared, hit space on the keyboard, then choose your own language. Check your disc first, 'cause DVDs are fragile media. if everything is ok. you can go back to that menu and choose install now. If it doesn't work,
2. Boot your windows up, insert your flashdrive, back it up, and use the Universal USB Installer. If it doesn't work:

   - Install VirtualBox on your windows, and load the image you've downloaded. use the internal usb boot creator to install ubuntu to your flashdrive. Since you are using a 64bit windows, you have to download the extension pack from virtualbox.org to support the usb module for virtual machine.

Well, that's all i can think of.